# to show active image if I clicked button

Tags: java, android

I want to show active image when I clicked button.But ,if I am not clicked,to show normal image style.How can I do that ?Please help me kindly.

**icon_home_config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home_button_hover" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home_button_hover" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_button"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ImageView**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_background" />
```

**btn_background.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this background.xml selector & put it in drawable folder & set image background to this selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" android:state_focused="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal"/>
</selector>
```

OR

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@drawable/normal" />

<stroke
    android:width="0dp"
    android:color="@drawable/pressed" />

<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />
```

set image background

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/background" />
```